How do I call a function on all clients when the host leaves the lobby in Unity Lobbies?
The package automatically disconnects all players and removes the lobby when the host leaves but I need to tell apart players leaving the lobby by themselves from being forced to leave because of lobby being deleted.
I have tried many different approaches and none of them worked. I am new to Unity's multiplayer and I don't exactly know why some of them didn't work but to sum up:
*I tried to check if the lobby still exists after the player leaves it but lobby is deleted after the player leaves so it's always still there
*I tried to listen to lobby being deleted by subscribing to LobbyDeleted but for some reason the event never fires.
*I tried to call a Rpc when host disconnects but the method never works. I assume it's because rpc can't be called after host has disconnected.
*I tried to listen playerleft events but when host leaves, it automatically kicks other players too so the client sees itself being kicked before the host leaves for some reason or I did something else wrong.
*I tried to check if the host still in the lobby when player is leaving the lobby but again, even if it's the host leaving, the clients disconnects before the host does (or it seems so)

When they leave themselves .. can't you handle that case yourself by simply setting some flag?

Posting this as an answer as I don't have enough rep to comment.
If you are only interested in the local client manually leaving a Lobby, then you could just toggle a local flag before doing so. If a Client disconnects from a Lobby, but doesn't have this flag enabled, it means they got kicked out.
If you are instead interested in warning the Lobby host that a Client left manually, then you could first send an RPC from the Client to the Host, informing them before leaving. Manual disconnects are simpler to handle because you can write your code in a way that makes the disconnection process happen only after your own checks.
As for the LobbyDeleted event not firing, are you calling SubscribeToLobbyEventsAsync() first? The docs don't mention this, but maybe only the Host can receive a LobbyDeleted event?
There's also a KickedFromLobby event that you could try and use.
